# Iterate through string and store numbers in array

Tags: c, string, token

I like to iterate through the string `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1` and store all numbers in a array. My code works for numbers between `0-9` but not for greater than `9` because I iterate just one step and scan the number. How can I store all numbers, not like in my current output : `1 3 6 1 2 1 2 2 1 10 0 1` (without linebreak)?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //char * string = "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.1"; /* OK */
    char * string = "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1"; /* NOK */
    static int oid_val_arr[256];
    char *oid_tmp = string;
    int idx = 0;
    while (*oid_tmp)
    {
        int number;
        if (sscanf(oid_tmp, "%d", &number) == 1)
        {
            oid_val_arr[idx] = number;
            idx++;
        }
        oid_tmp++; /* PROBLEM */
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("%d\n", oid_val_arr[i]);
}
```

Should I use [strtok()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)?

Comment: After a *successful* scan you *could* add `oid_tmp += log(oid_val_arr[idx]);`.

Comment: @alk can you explain what you mean? I dont get it.

Comment: `while(isdigit(*oid_tmp)) { oid_tmp++; } if(*oid_tmp == '.') { oid_tmp++; }` This will need to `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: Docs on `log10()` are here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.6.8; Doc log logarithm is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: Correction to [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782398/iterate-through-string-and-store-numbers-in-array#comment78522205_45782398): `... += log(...` should read `... += log10(...` Sry!

Comment: Forget `strtok`. Use **`strtol`** instead of `scanf`; it will give a pointer to the first non-matching character.

Comment: Use `%n` like [this](http://ideone.com/0Jh1r9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, change this:

```
if(sscanf(oid_tmp, "%d", &number) == 1)
```

to this:

```
if(sscanf(oid_tmp, "%d%n", &number, &len) == 1)
```

in order to get the length too. Then of course you would need to change your while loop like this:

```
while (*oid_tmp)
{
    int number;
    int len;
    if(sscanf(oid_tmp, "%d%n", &number, &len) == 1)
    {
        oid_val_arr[idx++] = number;
        oid_tmp += len;
    }
    else
    {
        ++oid_tmp;
    }
}
```

as BLUEPIXY said.

---

Another approach would be to use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 11

int main ()
{
  int arr[SIZE], i = 0; 
  char str[] ="1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,".");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    //printf ("%s\n",pch);
    arr[i++] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ".");
  }
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Splitting string "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1" into tokens:
1 3 6 1 2 1 2 2 1 10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

or instead of strtok

Function ignores more than one separator between the numbers.

```
int stringToIntArray(const char *string, char *separators, int *table, size_t tablesize, int ignoreinvalid)
{
    int result = (string == NULL || separators == NULL || table == NULL || !tablesize) * -1;
    char tmpbuff[50];
    char *tmpptr;
    int invalid = 0;


    if (!result)
    {
        while (*string)
        {
            invalid = 0;
            tmpptr = tmpbuff;
            while (*string && strchr(separators, *string) != NULL)  string++;
            while (*string && strchr(separators, *string) == NULL)
            {
                if (isdigit(*string)) *tmpptr++ = *string;
                else
                {
                    if (ignoreinvalid == 1)
                    {
                        invalid = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (ignoreinvalid == 2)
                    {
                        result = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                *string++;
            }
            if (result != -1)
            {
                if (invalid)
                {
                    while (*string && strchr(separators, *string) == NULL) string++;
                }
                else
                {
                    *tmpptr = '\0';
                    if (!strlen(tmpbuff)) break;
                    table[result++] = atoi(tmpbuff);
                    if (result == tablesize) break;
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

usage:

int ar[11];

```
int cnt = stringToIntArray("123,:0dddd3:0:;456", ",:;", &ar, 11, 0);
```

last parameter - 0 just ignores invalid symbols, 1 ignores the number, 2 breaks scanning with error. Return nomber of numbers found or -1 on error